# lubridate parsing vector of strings results in todays date

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a situation where I have many dimension tables and some of them contain date attributes, usually in ymd or ymd_hms like character strings. My goal was to reformat all of date variables into Date class. Since there are many dimension tables I decided to put them in a list of data.frames and just loop over every one of them, parse each column of dimension data.frames with ymd_hms function from lubridate package and select those columns that parsed correctly and put them back into my original dimension tables.

But, it happened that

`ymd_hms(., truncated = 3)` parsed succesfully also some data.frame columns that should not parse at all...that are just categorical variables (stored as character). Below I provide an exemple.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

my_test_df <- 
    structure(list(naziv.x = c("NI PODATKA", "TUJINA", "GRAD", 
                           "LJUBLJANA", "CELJE", "VELIKA POLANA"),
               datsp.x = c("2010-01-13 15:28:00", "2008-05-22 14:48:00",
                           "2007-03-29 12:14:00", "2007-03-29 12:14:00",
                           "2007-03-29 12:14:00", "2007-03-29 12:14:00")), 
          .Names = c("naziv.x",
                     "datsp.x"), 
          class = "data.frame", 
          row.names = c(NA, 6L))
```

Here is my data.frame:

```
        naziv.x             datsp.x
1    NI PODATKA 2010-01-13 15:28:00
2        TUJINA 2008-05-22 14:48:00
3          GRAD 2007-03-29 12:14:00
4     LJUBLJANA 2007-03-29 12:14:00
5         CELJE 2007-03-29 12:14:00
6 VELIKA POLANA 2007-03-29 12:14:00
```

here is my code that should succesfully parse only the second column:

```
my_test_df %>%
    mutate_each(funs(as.Date(ymd_hms(., truncated = 3))))
```

but it results in the data.frame below:

```
     naziv.x    datsp.x
1 2014-10-17 2010-01-13
2 2014-10-17 2008-05-22
3 2014-10-17 2007-03-29
4 2014-10-17 2007-03-29
5 2014-10-17 2007-03-29
6 2014-10-17 2007-03-29
```

**Why does that happen?**

My sessionInfo is below:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250    LC_MONETARY=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                       
[5] LC_TIME=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.3.0.2   lubridate_1.3.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1 DBI_0.3.1      digest_0.6.4   lazyeval_0.1.9 magrittr_1.0.1 memoise_0.2.1  parallel_3.1.1 plyr_1.8.1     Rcpp_0.11.3   
[10] stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matches` , `starts_with`, `ends_with`, `num_range` or `contains` etc to specify the column names that you want to apply the function.  If you don't have many number of columns, just use the column names.  I guess without specifying anything, it goes to the default ie. `everything` and applies the function.  For some reason, the columns that don't follow the `date` format in this case `naziv.x` gets today's date.  I don't know if it is a bug or not.

```
 my_test_df %>%
          mutate_each(funs(as.Date(ymd_hms(., truncated = 3))), starts_with("datsp"))
 #        naziv.x    datsp.x
 #1    NI PODATKA 2010-01-13
 #2        TUJINA 2008-05-22
 #3          GRAD 2007-03-29
 #4     LJUBLJANA 2007-03-29
 #5         CELJE 2007-03-29
 #6 VELIKA POLANA 2007-03-29
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will have to find a way with matches, starts_with, ends_with, num_range or contains then...I thought that the parsing would fail on naziv.x...like it does if truncated is set to 0.

Comment: @Miha Trost Yes, I was also thinking it that way.  If you apply the function on that specific column it is all NAs. `ymd_hms(my_test_df$naziv.x)#[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA`.  Infact, I get the same result of date conversion with `data.table`. ie.  `setDT(my_test_df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.Date(ymd_hms(x, truncated=3)))]`

Comment: Do you have any experience in bug reporting? Do you think I should file one?

Comment: @Miha Trost You could report the bug, but at this point, I think it is not an issue with `dplyr` alone as `data.table` also shows the same output.  Here is a link to file dplyr bug `https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues` or for lubridate `https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues`